# Why validation message is shown below of select input with select2 class?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2, laravel-validation

In  Laravel 8 / "jquery": "^3.4 / bootstrap 4.6  app I use [proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation](https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation) library for validation on client side and it works ok, but I have a problems
when validation rule is applied to select input with select2 plugin applied, like:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="document_type">
            Document type <span class="text-danger">*</span>
        </label>
        <select class="form-control select2" id="document_type" name="document_type">
            <option value="">Select...</option>
            @if($documentTypeLabelValueList)
                @foreach($documentTypeLabelValueList as $key=>$value)
                    <option
                        value="{{ $key }}"
                        {{ old('document_type', ( $educationData->document_type ?? -1 ) )==$key ? 'selected':'' }}
                    >
                        {{ $value }}
                    </option>
                @endforeach
            @endif
        </select>
        @error('document_type')
        <p class="validation_error">{{ $message }}</p>
        @enderror
    </div>
</div>
```

Validation error message is shown ABOVE of select input, but not below, as all rest inputs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTA6M.jpg

Select input are initialized with:

```
$('.select2').select2();
```

If from Select input remove “select2” class then validation message is below. What I see in browser's console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FVDD.jpg

Why so and how can it be fixed?

**MODIFIED BLOCK :**

1. Looks like piece of code:

   ```
   @error('document_type')
       <p class="validation_error">{{ $message }}</p>
   @enderror
   ```

   is from prior version, when validation was made with form submittion.  If to remove it all works the same.
2. At the printscreen https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FVDD.jpg I see that:

   - a) original select input is hidden,
   - b) validation error  span is located AFTER hidden original select input
   - c) new select2 select input is located AFTER validation error  span and that is why  it looks like so
   - d) But how can it be fixed. We have class of validation error span `invalid-feedback` Are there some css/javascript tricks to move any span element with class `invalid-feedback` below of next span element with class `select2 select2-container select2-container--default`?

Comment: It does so because the validation message inserts itself just after the element with `is-invalid` class, in this case the `select` itself. Though I am confused as to why your `<p>...</p>` is not visible in the screenshot?

Comment: It confused me too. Any ideas how can it be fixed?

Comment: Trying to work on it, could you upload a screenshot of another error (inspected in the browser) which is placed normally?

Comment: Okay never mind that, I checked out the package you're using and it turns out it just places the errors below the named fields, and doesn't use your `<p>...</p>` at all, but creates its own spans. I don't see any option to move it in the documentation.

Comment: Please look at MODIFIED BLOCK

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it by editing the following file:

```
resources\views\vendor\jsvalidation\bootstrap.php
```

I've changed this:

```
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.parent('.input-group').length ||
                element.prop('type') === 'checkbox' || element.prop('type') === 'radio') {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                // else just place the validation message immediately after the input
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        },
```

Into this:

```
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.parent('.input-group').length ||
                element.prop('type') === 'checkbox' || element.prop('type') === 'radio') {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                // else just place the validation message immediately after the input
            } else if (element.parent().children('.select2').length){
                error.insertAfter(element.parent().children('.select2'));
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        },
```

Then you should also remove the following code, because it's no longer needed:

```
    @error('document_type')
    <p class="validation_error">{{ $message }}</p>
    @enderror
```